# Is a route like `"controller#action"` not the same as `:controller => 'controller'` and `:action => 'action'`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I have a Rails 3.1 app where I just got some weird behavior.

I had two routes declared as follows:

```
# OLD METHOD
get 'accept_terms', :to => "users_terms#show"
put 'accept_terms', :to => "users_terms#accept'"
```

Running `rake routes` included the following:

```
# accept_terms 
#   GET    /accept_terms(.:format)    {:action=>"show",    :controller=>"users_terms"}
#   PUT    /accept_terms(.:format)    {:action=>"accept'", :controller=>"users_terms"}
```

The `GET` worked fine, but the `PUT` produced this error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'accept'' could not be found for UsersTermsController):
```

I confirmed that the action did exist on that controller.

While tinkering around with the problem, I changed the route declarations to:

```
get 'accept_terms', :controller => 'users_terms', :action => 'show'
put 'accept_terms', :controller => 'users_terms', :action => 'accept'
```

Running `rake routes` produced:

```
# accept_terms 
# GET    /accept_terms(.:format)      {:controller=>"users_terms", :action=>"show"}
# PUT    /accept_terms(.:format)      {:controller=>"users_terms", :action=>"accept"}
```

With this, both `GET` and `PUT` worked fine.

**Is `:to => "controller#action` not the same as `:controller => 'controllerName', :action => 'actionName'`**?

The only difference I see in the produced routes is the order of `:action` and `:controller`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old method you end the `users_terms#accept` with both a single quote and a double quote.

Comment: By gosh, you're right. Well, I'll vote to delete this question. Reason: shame / "too localized". :)